# Cannot launch Chrome on Ubuntu-14

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, segmentation-fault

I am trying to install google chrome (latest stable), onto my Ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS), and whichever which way I try to install it, it does not launch.

What I did here was follow the [first answer's instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome), and then run the `google-chrome-stable` command from the command prompt.

If I do that however, I get the following error:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
[12282:12299:0526/194708.763068:FATAL:nss_util.cc(631)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So, I am not sure what this error is, but more importantly, how to go about resolving it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It says you need to update NSS:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3 -U

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Why install, just update is required

Comment: Ok, would `sudo apt-get install libnss3 -U` update in one line?